# Output to 2 decimal places?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to change output of this to be 2 dec places:

```
dir c:\ -Recurse -File | sort-object -property length | select name, @{Name=‘Length (GB)’;Expression={$_.Length / 1GB}} -last 10
```

I have tried inserting `{0:F2} -f` before the `{$_.Length / 1GB}`

But thats not working

I was thinking of using `[Math]::round` somehow, but not having success.

I'm still learning, can someone show me how to change that calculated property?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on this, it works both ways!

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Recurse -File | 
    Sort-Object -Property length | 
        Select-Object -Last 10 -Property name, 
            @{Name = 'Length (GB rounded)'; Expression = {'{0:F2}' -f ($_.Length / 1GB)}} ,
            @{Name = 'Length (GB formatted)'; Expression = {[Math]::Round($_.Length / 1GB, 2)}}
```